# Автоматическое срабатывание кода после отображения формы c#

Tags: c#, winforms, form

Я запускаю первую форму и нажимаю кнопку со следующим кодом:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox.Text != "")
    {
        DownloadForm downloadForm = new DownloadForm();
        downloadForm.SendData(comboBox.Text.ToLower());
        //downloadForm.Show(); пробовал так
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Вы не сделали выбор!");
    }
}
```

Метод `SendData` (если вдруг надо) :

```
public void SendData(string localGenomeName)
{
    this.name = localName;
    //this.Show(); так тоже не выходит
}
```

И некий код (Не этот, но для упрощения пусть будет такой) с записью данных в методе `DownloadForm_Load()`, который вызывается после события `Load`:

```
private void DownloadForm_Load()
{
    if(this.name != "")
    {
         this.name = "Hello, Wrold!";
    }
}
```

Это код я записал в метод `DownloadForm_Show()`, который вызывается после события Show. Но результат тот же, что и если бы я добавил этот код в `Load`, а не в `Show`:

```
private void DownloadForm_Show()
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.name);
}
```

[image: Неудовлетворительный результат]

Как сделать так, чтобы форма отображалась правильно, ко всеми элементами перед исполнением кода из `DownloadForm_Show`?

Answer (score 0):

Например можно так

[image: пример работы]

Главная форма

```
struct Address
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public Address(string title, string url)
    {
        Title = title;
        Url = url;
    }
}

public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //источник данных для ComboBox
    private BindingSource _bsLinks;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";

        SetComboBox();
        _buttonDownload.Click += ButtonDownload_Click;
    }

    private void SetComboBox()
    {
        //формируем список
        var addresses = new List<Address>
        {
            new Address("Яндекс", "https://yandex.ru/"),
            new Address("Stackoverflow на русском", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"),
        };
        //привязка к комобобоксу
        _bsLinks = new BindingSource();
        _bsLinks.DataSource = addresses;
        _comboBoxAddresses.DataSource = _bsLinks;
        _comboBoxAddresses.DisplayMember = nameof(Address.Title);
    }

    private void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //получаем текущий выбранный адрес
        var address = (Address)_bsLinks.Current;
        //загружаем и показываем форму (в конструктор передаем загружаемый адрес)
        var formDownload = new FormDownload(address.Url);
        formDownload.Text = $"Загрузка {address.Title}...";
        formDownload.Owner = this;
        formDownload.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        formDownload.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Форма загрузки

```
public partial class FormDownload : Form
{
    private string _url;

    public FormDownload(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(url));

        InitializeComponent();

        _url = url;
        this.Load += FormDownload_Load;
    }

    //асинхронно загружаем сайт
    private async void FormDownload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _progressBar.Value = 50;
        try
        {
            //!!!
            await LoadSite();
        }
        finally
        {
            _progressBar.Value = 100;
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadSite()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var message = await client.GetAsync(_url);
            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _textBox.Text = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

    }
}
```